# How to search post by subcategories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to search post by subcategories in wordpress. Is it even possible? I was going through the wordpress plugin for searching it. The name is "Facetious Search", but it is limited to categories only. I have googled a lot for this, but got no solution.

Comment: Do you have any code already written to attempt this? Please ask for help in fixing issues in your code rather than asking for a fully written answer. We prefer to help, not babysit

Comment: yes i have mentioned the name of plugin it is" Facetious Search"

Comment: just put code over here ...no have time to see your plugin and we are not here for write code for you understand .

Comment: You mentioned that the plugin does not do what you need to so that is not the solution that you're looking for. The alternative is to write your own plugin or modify the mentioned plugin. What is the problem that you're facing when modifying it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> if plugin doesnt provide you desire output then you can get the post of sub category by manually ie from data base.
> First you need to parent category id then you can get its sub category from table wp_term_taxonomy
> after geting subcategory list. you can get the object_id from table Table: wp_term_relationships where term_taxonoy_id=sub category_id
> and From boject_id you can get the post from wp_posts table where object_id is the post id. eg


<?php global $wpdb;$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;

$subcateogyr_list=$wpdb->get_results("Select * from ".$prefix."term_taxonomy WHERE parent='main_category_id'");

foreach($subcateogyr_list as $subcat

    $object_id=$wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$prefix."term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id='$subcat['term_id']'");

        foreach($object_id as $object_post){

            $post_detail=$wpdb->get_row("select * from ".$prefix."posts where id='$object_post['object_id']");

            print_r($post_detial);//you will get the post detail

        }
}
?>
```